# Javascript AJAX HTML Response InsertBefore Function

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, eval, responsetext

**JAVASCRIPT Problem NoT JQUERY**

```
with(req = new XMLHttpRequest())open("GET",url,true),onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (req.readyState==4 && req.status==200){
        proposalTable.insertBefore(req.responseText,proposalTable.lastChild.previousSibling);
    }
},send(null);
```

req.responseText is

```
<tr><td>Row1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row3</td></tr>
```

I want to insert this responseText before the last Row of Table (#proposalTable)
My code is not working because .insertBefore function's 1st parameter should be an element i think

Comment: Well what does the response text look like?  Why are you passing it through `eval()`?

Comment: ok, i have modified my question, now i think it is explained good. thanks

Comment: It's still not clear why you're passing that response text to `eval()` (and `eval()` in the parent window, for some reason).  It's HTML, not JavaScript.  It's just going to cause errors (which you should be seeing in the error console).

Comment: i suppose eval() is to convert responseText to HTML

Comment: and window.parent to work fine with all browser. for some browser eval() will not work without window.parent

Comment: No, that's just not true, and passing the text to `eval()` "to convert it to HTML" makes absolutely no sense if it looks like what you posted in the question.

Comment: i have made changes to my question. if even i remove eval and put req.innerHTML as first parameter of insertBefore, it will not work becuase first parameter should be an element. What element can be the parent of "tr", does that make sense now

Answer (score 0):

I will use jquery to insert the rows, something like:

```
with(req = new XMLHttpRequest())open("GET","ajax.php? page=proposal&contractid="+x,true),onreadystatechange=function(){
  if (req.readyState==4 && req.status==200){
    var $my_table = $('#my_table_id > tbody'); // we actually insert into the tBody
    var $last_row = $my_table.find('> tr:last');
    var $new_rows = $(req.responseText);
    $new_rows.appendTo($my_table);
    $last_row.appendTo($my_table);
  }
},send(null);
```

this basically will get the job done, I haven't test this code, but this is the basic idea

Comment: you can always parse the response string and split it by TRs and insert the elements from a FOR / WHILE, etc loop

Comment: Yes you are correct but its not perfect solution. it can be done more better because jquery is also handling it some how.

Answer (score 0):

It can be used the insertRow() function.
Here`s an example:

```
<table id="proposalTable">
<tr><td>Row1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row3</td></tr>
</table>
<script>
var eltd = document.createElement('td');
eltd.innerHTML = 'New row';
var eltable = document.getElementById('proposalTable');
var elrows = eltable.getElementsByTagName('tr');
var nrrows = elrows.length - 1;
eltable.insertRow(nrrows);
eltable.rows[nrrows].appendChild(eltd); 
</script>
```

Comment: your answer is appreciated but i need to insert a number of tr and tr is already the part of innerHTML... problem is need to insert HTML instead of an element at second last row.